# Aggregating values with filtering based on values in other tables

Tags: excel

I have two tables, Transactions and Accounts.

Transactions table looks like this (marked columns are primary keys):

```
| ID* | Date       | Amount | Debit | Credit |
+-----+------------+--------+-------+--------+
|   1 | 03/11/2015 |   $100 | B     | A      |
|   2 | 03/12/2015 |    $50 |       | A      |
|   3 | 03/13/2015 |   $400 | C     | A      |
|   4 | 03/14/2015 |   $200 | A     |        |
|   5 | 03/14/2015 |   $150 | D     | A      |
```

And Accounts table looks like this:

```
| Name* | Liquidity |
+-------+-----------+
| A     |         1 |
| B     |         1 |
| C     |         2 |
| D     |         3 |
```

What I want to achieve is summing the amounts in Transactions tables where Credit is the name of an account with Liquidity of k, and Debit is either blank or the name of an account with Liquidity of k + 1 or above. For the above case, if k = 1, the result would be $50 (Row 2) + $400 (Row 3) + $150 (Row 5) = $600.

If it were SQL, then the query would look like this:

```
select sum(amount)
from transactions
where credit in (select name from accounts where liquidity = 1)
  and (debit is null or
       debit in (select name from accounts where liquidity > 1))
```

Or this:

```
select sum(amount)
from transactions
left join accounts as c on transactions.credit = c.name
left join accounts as d on transactions.debit = d.name
where c.liquidity = 1 and (d.liquidity is null or d.liquidity > c.liquidity)
```

Actually I also need to filter the rows by time (specifically by month), but I think that would be easy.

How can I do this in Excel? I tried using SUMIFS with VLOOKUP, but I can't make it work. I have many accounts, so manually listing all criteria for SUMIFS is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

This *array formula* seems to fit the bill. It uses `INDEX` in its array form and zeroes any values that do not match by multiplying by `FALSE` (e.g. *zero* or *0*). What is left over is summed as the total.

[image: SUM across INDEX with criteria]

The *array formula* in I9 is,

```
=SUM(INDEX($C$2:$C$99*($E$2:$E$99=G9)*(IF($D$2:$D$99="", 1, SUMIF($G$2:$G$5, $D$2:$D$99, $H$2:$H$5)>H9)), , ))
```

Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>.